# One line to check if column names in 2 dataframes contain a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I am using for a X and a Y dataset when training a linear regression. I want to check if both dataframes contain a column of a given name, e.g. datetime.

The dataframes column names are simple

```
Index    col1   colY   datetime_10min
```

or

```
Index    datetime_15min     col1    colZ
```

I can see ***if a given string is contained in the columns*** using col for col:

```
time_col = [col for col in df.columns if "datetime" in col]
```

as long as time_col is not empty for both df1 and df2, I know my condition is satisfied. But that is a 2 line implementation at minimum...is there a more elegant way to do this in one line?

EDIT:
It's not technically a 2 line implementation but it becomes unwieldy if there are more than 2 dataframes being checked

eg:

```
if [col for col in df1.columns if "datetime" in col] and 
[col for col in df2.columns if "datetime" in col] and 
[col for col in df3.columns if "datetime" in col]......
```

the questions is how do I reduce the above into a more friendly solution **while being aware that I might not know the column string exactly** , if there is one in pandas already

Answer (score 1):

You can check directly if the column exist in the dataframe columns.

```
if 'datetime' in df.columns:
    print("yes it exists")
```

which mean in your case if you want to check if the column exists in both dataframes then it should be something like this:

```
if 'datetime' in df1.columns and 'datetime' in df2.columns:
    print("yes it exists in both dfs")
```

***Edit***

here is an example that you can use if you have to check if a column name matches in all multiple dataframe columns:

```
 # maybe you can even omit the list(). I don't remember what is the type of df.columns. maybe you ll not need to convert it to a list

 if 'datetime' in list(df1.columns) + list(df2.columns) + list(df3.columns):
    print("yes it exists in all dfs")
```

Now if your string can be included in the list and does not need to match then you can use:

```
 if [col for col in list(df1.columns) + list(df2.columns) + list(df3.columns) if 'datetime' in col]:
    print("yes it exists in all dfs")
```

I believe that will solve your problem

Comment: This evaluates to false for me for some reason while the col for col statement does not though. 

EDIT: For this to work I need to be exact in the column name. Therefore "datetime_10min" evaluates false if I check for "datetime". The question is if i can be flexible in the column names while searching

Comment: In your col for col statement, you don't check if it exists in both dfs. You are checking only for one df. You need to edit your question because I'm having trouble understanding what is your goal here

Comment: Right, sorry, in the post I mentioned that to use the col for col method the solution is inherently a 2 line way to do it. This isn't 100% true but it's a really really long 1 line:


if [col for col in df1.columns if "datetime" in col] and [col for col in df2.columns if "datetime" in col]:
#do something


I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this

Comment: Part of the impetus for the question is that I have more than 2 dataframes and I want to check all of them to ensure they have the desired column in some form.

Comment: @Mike check my edit. If I understand you right. that would work fine. Notice the comment about the list() converter

Comment: So that works but still only if the string being searched for is the exact match of the column name. In the original post I gave examples of how the names might not match with "datetime_15min" and "datetime_10min". The col for col method ignores this restriction which is the other part I am probably not being clear about. I'm wondering if there is no easy way to do this.

Comment: @Mike alright I adjusted the code to work with your case. I think it will work fine for you now

Comment: @Mike Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you in order to close the question and help other people